# Authors on the philosophical impact of the discovery of an Extraterrestrial civilization

Tags: reference-request, sociology, thought-experiment

Is humanity ready to accept the existence of an extraterrestrial species? Would the average citizen of the XXI century would like to know or perhaps It would be better to society to remain ignorant? Knowing the way humans have been treating each other in the past, what would be our natural response to this event? Would that be great as Ronald Reagan told Gorbachov ([ref video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uD2186Yh0Uc)) because we could forget our little differences? Is humanity really ready for this? **Are there any serious authors who ponder abut this?**

**UPDATE**

U.S. Navy confirms UFO videos as real. CNN video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=60ZJQ4I7_3M).

NASA Chief Scientist Jim Green thinks news of life on Mars is coming soon, and the public isn't prepared to hear it [ref here](https://edition.cnn.com/2019/09/30/us/nasa-life-on-mars-jim-green-scn-trnd/index.html).

Comment: this is probably the philosophical question of the millennia then again too advanced for this forum...

Comment: This is a  area for opinion and fiction, so it doesnt really fit here.

Comment: @CriglCragl not really. Some credible people have taken this matter seriously. Remember heliocentrism and Darwin both revolutions of the mind people had trouble with that took centuries to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some literature on the subject:

**"Are We Alone?" by [Paul Davies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Davies)**

**"Contact" (Novel) and "Pale Blue Dot" by [Carl Sagan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Sagan)**